# drag down orbot icon to display expanded notifications

Tags: orbot

lg e980 4.4.2 kitkat AT&T us. Updated orbot & orweb. Now expanded notifications are absent. No longer able to see which countries tor is bouncing around in. How can I fix this? Also orbot is no longer visible in task manager. Did the upgrades do this? Should I uninstall and reinstall orbot & orweb?

Comment: Reistalled LG stock browser which was tango uniform. Still TU. Removed supersu, orbot and orweb. Reinstalled all. No joy. This morning all works well.??????

Answer (score 1):

What version are you using? If it's the latest version, check your log where you might find info about IP and country.

Comment: The expanded notifications don't always work.